# Output all values from an object in an HTLM5 data-attribute

Tags: jquery, html

Why does the following code only output the first of the two values from the HTML code below?

JS

```
var airportOptions = $.each($(".entry-listing").data("airports"), function(k,v) {
        console.log(v); 
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="entry-listing" data-airports="{ "LHR": "London Heathrow", "LHR":"London Gatwick" }">
```

Comment: Aren't those quotes ending the attribute and causing an error?

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't just print `{ `

Comment: you have the same key repeated twice... `LHR`... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/V3X4H/1/

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming you did actually get at least one object as you state in your question even though the HTML is malformed. If that is the case the problem definitely exists in the duplicate key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key LHR is used twice:

```
{ "LHR": "London Heathrow", "LHR":"London Gatwick" }
```

Keys in objects should be unique, eg:

```
{ "LHR": "London Heathrow", "LGW":"London Gatwick" }
```

Working html:

```
<div class="entry-listing" data-airports='{ "LHR": "London Heathrow", "LGW":"London Gatwick" }'></div>
```

And js

```
$.each($(".entry-listing").data("airports"), function (k, v) {
    console.log(v);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code -

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5caDp/1/)**

```
var airportOptions = $.each($(".entry-listing").data("airports"), function(k,v) {
       congsole.log(v); 
    });
```

Comment: Not really, `consgole.log` and this doesnt print out the objects but each letter of the string separate.

Comment: According to his code each will print every character separately

Comment: Not if your quotations are correct: http://jsfiddle.net/5caDp/2/ . I think askers HTML is malformed because it's theoretic code. At least I hope so!